# How to return FHitResult in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I created Action Mapping function for my Character Blueprint in UE4 with C++ and decided to call it on Blueprints, but i need to return FHitResult value to continue. I can't use return since C++ does not allow to return value that differs from functions type so i don't know what to do.

```
void AMeCharacter::Interact() {
    FHitResult OutHit;
    FVector Start = Camera->GetComponentLocation();

    // alternatively you can get the camera location
    // FVector Start = FirstPersonCameraComponent->GetComponentLocation();

    FVector ForwardVector = Camera->GetForwardVector();
    FVector End = ((ForwardVector * 150.f) + Start);
    FCollisionQueryParams CollisionParams;

    DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), Start, End, FColor::Red, false, 3, 0.5);
    bool bHit = GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(OutHit, Start, End, ECC_Visibility, CollisionParams);

    if (bHit)
    {
        if (!OutHit.GetActor())
            return;
        if (OutHit.GetActor()->GetClass()->ImplementsInterface(UInteractionInterface::StaticClass())) {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *OutHit.GetActor()->GetName());
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT("Implements Interface"));
        }
        else
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT("Doesn't implement interface"));

        //IInteractionInterface* Interface = Cast<IInteractionInterface>(OutHit.GetActor());
        //if (Interface) {
        //  Interface->OnInteracted();
        //}

    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you change the method's return type to `FHitResult`?

Comment: If you can't change the return type but you can change the parameters add an `FHitResult&` parameter and assign it to whatever you want.

Comment: Why do you need to return it and where are you returning it to? I would expect this function to cause an interaction with `OutHit.GetActor()`, not return anything.